Extract column name depending on a specific value in dataframe
I have the following data:
my_data <- tribble(
  ~item1, ~item2,
  "car", "ferrari",
  "house", "3 bed",
  NA, "3"
)

I am trying to extract the name of the column, in which "house" exists
I have tried:
my_data %>%
mutate(across(everything(), ~str_detect(.x , "house")))


which returns:
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  item1 item2
  <lgl> <lgl>
1 FALSE FALSE
2 TRUE  FALSE
3 NA    FALSE

And this is where I'm stuck, trying to extract the column "item1", I have tried using the function any() but that condenses the whole thing to TRUE.
Looking for a dplyr/purrr solution please. Thanks.
Edit:
There isn't a need to treat my question in such a broad brush way and just close it. The 1st "similar" question doesn't use dplyr and subsets the data, which is not what I have asked. And I appreciate that the 2nd "similar" does apply the same function, however doesn't return for the name of the column as a character like I have asked... i.e. I wouldn't have known you can apply names straight after. And there is also a discussion about whether where is needed, which none of the other questions discuss.

You want only the column name or the column values as well?

Just the column name please, no need for values. This is because we have found a quirk between different versions of R labelling columns as "X1" or "...1" so we are finding a way to identify the column name based on how the user's environment reads the file

names(Filter(\(x) "house" %in% x, my_data)) in base R

Using select(where()):
library(dplyr)

my_data %>%
  select(where(\(x) "house" %in% x)) %>%
  names()
# "item1"


FYI where is not needed here, e.g. my_data %>% select(\(x) "house" %in% x) %>% names(), only when using Formula shorthand ~

@AndreWildberg It used to be that you could directly pass a predicate function into  select. But that was changed. I believe its maintained for backward compatibility, but the advice is to always pass the predicate function into where.  Since the function \(x) "house" %in% x is a predicate function, it should be wrapped within where. Whether it uses native lambda or when using the rlang lambda/ from formula functions

Try this:
result <- my_data %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), 
               names_to = "column_name", 
               values_to = "value") %>%
  filter(value == "house") %>%
  pull(column_name)



#output
    print(result)
    [1] "item1"

